# Git not pushing new files to remote

Tags: git

I used the tutorial here - http://sebduggan.com/blog/deploy-your-website-changes-using-git/ - to configure a remote git repository on my UAT server. So now, after I commit changes, I can just run

```
git push uat
```

to push the changes to my UAT server. Everything works fine for existing files. They get updated on the UAT server. However, when I add a new file to my repository, it doesn't get pushed up to UAT. I'm having to manually FTP those files up.

Does anyone know why new files aren't being copied up?

Comment: Did you add the files, then commit?

Comment: Can you run `git status` amd show us the results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The steps for pushing to a repository are as below:

```
git add . (you can instead of . specify the files you want to add, . is file/directory globbing)
git commit -m 'commit message'
git push uat
```

Comment: I use the git plugin in Zend Studio's IDE. It normally does the "add" and "commit" for me when I commit files. I think what happened is that I created a folder and some files in Windows Explorer, and didn't refresh my project folder in Zend Studio. So when I committed, it didn't know that the new folder and files existed. An "F5" to refresh the project, then another commit fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you correctly added the new files to your repository they should pushed up with the rest of your repository.

Be sure you did a `git add` on the files to add it to your respository, not just the project folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you're committing, but you're doing it wrong. You didn't add your new files before committing.